# How to execute a command as a root user in ansible hosts

Tags: ansible

I have 3 VM's for ansible as follows:

1. `master`
2. `host1`
3. `host2`

`ansible` is installed and configured correctly. no issue with that part.

So I have this command I need to run. Before going to execute this command using `ansible`, I will show you how to do this **without ansible** :

I want to install update the packages first, so I am logged into the VM as a normal user (ubuntut) and execute like this:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

As you can see, I have executed a `sudo` command when I am logged in as the `ubuntu` user but not as a `root` user.

So above command is executed with `sudo` but user is `ubuntu`

I want this scenario to be done using ansible.

My **Question:** How to execute a command that contains `sudo` using `ansible` but when logged in as a different user

So my `playbook` will look like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
      become: ubuntu
      apt:
        upgrade: yes
        update_cache: yes
```

But where can I add the `sudo` part in above `playbook` ? does it add automatically?

What if I want to execute a command like this, logged in user as `ubuntu`:

```
sudo apt-get install docker
```

How can I do this `sudo` part in `ansible` while `become: ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a command as sudo, You can do something like this :

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
      become: ubuntu

      # this will fail because /opt needs permissions
      # shell: echo hello > /opt/testfile

      # this will work
      shell: "sudo sh -c 'echo hello > /opt/testfile'"

      # use this to verify output
      register: out
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out }}"
```

NOTE: you will get this warning:

> "Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather
> than running sudo"

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, you can find a detailed explanation and examples in ansible documentation.
[1]https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
      become: true
      become_user: ubuntu
      shell: echo hello > /opt/testfile

      # use this to verify output
      register: out
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out }}"
```